# Load WP Admin scripts in a child theme functions file

Tags: wordpress

All,
I'm using a plugin that enqueues some scripts in the admin section of wordpress. I want the same functionality built in a page template. I noticed the main difference between is it tries to use the load-scripts.php like this:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/bmt/multi-site/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&amp;load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-so&amp;load%5B%5D=rtable,postbox,svg-painter,heartbeat,wp-auth-check,jquery-ui-datepicker,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-ui-slider,jquery-touch-punch,&amp;load%5B%5D=iris,wp-color-picker,thickbox&amp;ver=4.0.1'></script>`

I want to specifically enqueue the same scripts from my functions.php child theme page. I specifically am worried about the postbox which sits in wp-admin/js/ How can I do this?